# How to reduce matrix cols in python?

Tags: python, loops, csv, matrix

I have a csv file with lot of data, 22 cols and 10000 rows. 
First row is titles and all other rows are data.
I read from the file. (Just read, I don't want to change the original file)
Now I want to reduce the number of cols and save just 3 cols, by the title name and save it. The order of cols can be change from file to file, sometimes the "LUX" col will be in col number 5, and sometimes in col number 20, or 8, etc.. 
So far I got this:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|') # open the csv file

medianGoodPixels = [] #vector to pixels
Lux = [] #vector to LUX
sdVer = [] # vector to the version
NewCsvTable = [] #will be a matrix with 3 cols, LUX, pixels, and version

for row in spamreader:
    if row == "LUX": 
         #Here I'm stuck
```

I realized that row like this, will give all the row in each iteration so ectually in the second iteration, it will be just data of the second row.
I need somehow to use 2 loops I guess, but do not know how exactly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list.index` on the header row to find the index of various headers.

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|') # open the csv file
    medianGoodPixels = [] #vector to pixels
    Lux = [] #vector to LUX
    sdVer = [] # vector to the version
    NewCsvTable = [] #will be a matrix with 3 cols, LUX, pixels, and version
    header = next(spamreader)  #Returns the header 
    lux_col, pixel_col, version_col = header.index('LUX'), header.index('pixel'),\
                                      header.index('version')

    #Now iterate over rest of the rows. 
    for row in spamreader:
        Lux.append(row[lux_col])
        sdVer.append(row[version_col])
        medianGoodPixels.append(row[pixel_col])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a work for specialized `csv` module class `csv.DictReader`, that uses the first row of the document to find out what the colum names are, then returns one dictionary per row.

Example:

```
Lux, sdVer, medianGoodPixels = [], [], []
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for dict_row in csv_reader:
        Lux.append(dict_row['LUX'])
        sdVer.append(dict_row['version'])
        medianGoodPixel.append(dict_row['pixel'])
```